# Python append to a value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, append, key-value

I have a following dictionary:

```
d = {'key':{'key2':[]}}
```

Is there any way to append to d['key']?

I want to get:

```
d = {'key':{'key2':[], 'key3':[]}}
```

d['key'] = ['key3'] apparently does not produce the desired outcome..

I know I can do

```
d = {'key': [{'key2': []}]}
```

and then append to d['key'] in a loop, but I am trying to avoid that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for

```
d['key']['key3'] = []
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution.

```
d['key'].update({'key3':[]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `d["key"]` is a dictionary, you can set keys in this dictionary as usual:

```
e = d["key"]
e["key3"] = []
```

or simply

```
d["key"]["key3"] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not trying:

```
d['key']['key3'] = []
```

That should work.